# Is there a way to calculate root mean square error for several lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python code that calculates the root mean square error for an experimental list and several simulated lists. The simplest solution would be to define the RMSE equation several times for each different simulation:

```
import numpy as np
import math

experimental = [1,2,3,4,5]
simulated = [1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1]

MSE = np.square(np.subtract(experimental,simulated)).mean() 

RMSE = math.sqrt(MSE)
print("Root Mean Square Error:\n")
print(RMSE)

#Second RMSE

simulated1 = [5,4,3,2,1]

MSE1 = np.square(np.subtract(experimental,simulated1)).mean() 

RMSE1 = math.sqrt(MSE1)

print("Root Mean Square Error1:\n")
print(RMSE1)
```

But this is inefficient. I tried the simulated lists into another list and then used a for loop to return RMSE values.

```
import numpy as np
import math

experimental = [1,2,3,4,5]
simulated1 = [1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1]
simulated2 = [5,4,3,2,1]

MSE[i] = np.square(np.subtract(experimental,simulated[i])).mean() 

RMSE[i] = math.sqrt(MSE[i])

sim_list = [simulated1, simulated2]

for i in sim_list:
    print RMSE[i](experimental, simulated[i])
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. And I just follow your thinking: traverse the list of simulated, and calculate the RMSE for each of them. As @Martian Coder says, you can use `mean_squared_error` functions for a cleaner implementation.

```
import numpy as np
import math
experimental = [1,2,3,4,5]
simulated1 = [1.6,2.5,2.9,3,4.1]
simulated2 = [5,4,3,2,1]


def RMSE(experimental, simulated):
    return math.sqrt(np.square(np.subtract(experimental, simulated)).mean())


sim_list = [simulated1, simulated2]

for sim in sim_list:
    print(RMSE(experimental, sim))
```

Comment: my advise is to use `sklearn` libaray `mean_squared_error` functions but still everything is okay

Comment: Ofcourse you are right, and I just follow the thinking of @Benjamin Atterberry to help him understand. : )